# How to mapping different field with @JsonProperty

Tags: java, jackson

I want to mapping fieldA in ClassA to fieldB in ClassB with annotation @JsonProperty. According to the output at [1], it worked! But when I serialize the ClassB instance, I get a **fieldA** in the json string at [2].

So how I can get output: `{"fieldB":"helloWorld"}` while I serializing `object b` at [2].

Class A:

```java
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
public class ClassA {

    private String fieldA;
}
```

Class B:

```java
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;


@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class ClassB {

    @JsonProperty(value = "fieldA")
    private String fieldB;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        ClassA a = new ClassA("helloWorld");
        ClassB b = mapper.convertValue(a, ClassB.class);
        
        // [1] output: ClassB(fieldB=helloWorld)
        System.out.println(b);
        
        // [2] output: {"fieldA":"helloWorld"}
        System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(b));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are misunderstanding output of your program. Calling `.toString()` on object and serializing it to JSON string won't produce the same result here. `.toString()` prints field name of class (`fieldB`) and serialization uses field name provided with annotation(so `fieldA`).

From serialized point of view, both ClassA and ClassB are the same models.

If you want to make sure that you'll get proper class while deserializing, just provide it then.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
ClassA a = mapper.readValue("{\"fieldA\":\"helloWorld\"}", ClassA.class); // ClassA(fieldA=helloWorld)
ClassB b = mapper.readValue("{\"fieldA\":\"helloWorld\"}", ClassB.class); // ClassB(fieldB=helloWorld);
```

Comment: Maybe I didn't describe my problem clearly. Actually, I want to know how I can get `output: {"fieldB":"helloWorld"}` at output[2].

Comment: You would need to remove `@JsonProperty` annotation, or use `fieldB` value here. Can you describe more clearly what you want to achieve? Do you want to use `fieldA` during deserialization and `fieldB` during serialization?